# Create a date parameter in R to pass into a Teradata query

Tags: r, teradata-sql-assistant

I have multiple Teradata queries. Each query declares a beginning date and end date:

```
DECLARE @DATE1 DATE = '2020-01-01';
DECLARE @DATE2 DATE = '2020-02-01';
```

I am using RStudio to run all the queries and joins, but I have to change the dates manually in each Teradata script. I saw something where I can use $(variable) that will call the variable from R into Teradata, but I get a syntax error.

Is there a way to declare my dates in R studio and pass DATE1 and DATE2 into the Teradata queries?

Comment: how are you passing the queries into teradata;

Comment: I'm using odbcConnect in the RODBC package and sqlQuery function to run the .sql file

Comment: are you reading the .sql file with readLines if so why not `sql <- readLines(path.to.sql)` then `sql<-stringr::replace_all(sql, c("2020-01-01"=newDate1, "2020-02-01"=newDate2))`

Comment: It wasn't the most ideal way to complete this, I had to tweak a few scripts, but this method worked. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome :)